# How to determine if user is already within region when CLLocationManager begins monitoring regions

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I have an app that is ranging beacons in the background. When I initialize my CLLocationManager instance I'm starting things off with the `startMonitoringForRegion` method. I am handling the `locationManager:didEnterRegion`, `locationManager:didExitRegion`, and `locationManager:didDetermineState:ForRegion` delegate methods. Within those methods I am turning ranging on/off.

This all seems to work great except when the `CLLocationManager` is initialized when the user is already present within the region. In that case neither `locationManager:didEnterRegion` nor `locationManager:DidDetermineState:ForRegion` are called until after I exit and then re-enter the region. I was always under the impression that this would at least trigger `locationManager:DidDetermineState:ForRegion` but that does not appear to be the case.

**Is there a way to determine if the user is initially within the region when I first fire off `startMonitoringForRegion` ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can invoke the manager's `requestStateForRegion` method. This will cause your delegate's `didDetermineState` method to be called asynchronously.